# Resources no app_globalresource

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resources

Tenho uma `class library` em que adicionei um arquivo `resx`, alguém sabe como eu posso em runtime colocar esse `resx` na `app_globalresource` para que ela fique disponível em toda a minha `app web mvc`?

Comment: Se é uma class library, porque ela foi adicionada como resource? Não entendi.

Answer (score 1):

Luciano
você pode adicionar o caminho do Resource na sua masterpage

Você pode tornar seus resource `público` e depois utilizá-lo da seguinte maneira

```
@MyResources = Projeto.DiretorioDeResx.Resources.Strings
//Projeto.DiretorioDeResx.Resources.Strings <- onde Strings é o nome do resource (String.resx), e o resto é o caminho(namespace) do arquivo.

@Html.ActionLink(MyResources.Novo,"Create");
```